# "Automatic date&time" set on/off programmatically

Tags: android, datetime, networking, time

I need to set current date & time from network provider or gps provider,
I have tried this but not worked

```
String timeSettings = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(
            this.getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME);
    if (timeSettings.contentEquals("0")) {
        android.provider.Settings.System.putString(
                this.getContentResolver(),
                android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, "1");
    }
    timeSettings = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(
            this.getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME);
```

And permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

But not working, Please tell what is going wrong and please tell if have any other solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only system apps can set the values , the installed application cannot change even though it has permissions.

The code to read if **auto time pref** is checked

```
Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME)
```

The code to read if **auto time zone pref** is checked

```
Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME_ZONE)
```

You can ask user to set if they are OFF.

You can set time and time zone programmatically , by reading the required values  .

The following is the code to set time

```
long now = // time set from timepicker or servertime 
int year, month, day; // from timepicker

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

am.setTime(now);
```

Permission required : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME" />`

Comment: Thanks Rahul, You mean I have to get time from server and set to time using SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis()

Comment: I just used this Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  c.set(2015, 1, 1, 12, 00, 00);
  
  System.setCurrentTimeMillis(c.getTimeInMillis());
  It is showing "The method setCurrentTimeMillis(long) is undefined for the type System" error

Comment: Sorry, Its my mistake SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(c.getTimeInMillis());
  System time is not changing using "setCurrentTimeMillis()", If you have any other solution please tell me

Comment: Let me know what exactly you can , code to change system time ? , one installed apps cannot change time zone.

Comment: Yes, I need code that change system time, Ok I have used this for now
         startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));It navigate to change Automatic date & time

Comment: Thanks Rahul, but what is tzid and Manifest file has error of 'Permission is only granted to system apps'

Comment: I removed it.. it is used to set time zone , but only system apps can set time zone . accept the answer

Comment: You are right, What about  Manifest file has error of 'Permission is only granted to system apps, So It is not possible to set time using my aap?

Comment: it is possible to set time but not time zone

Comment: Manifest file not accepting this permission '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME" />' showing ''Permission is only granted to system apps' error

Comment: Is that any API problem?

Comment: @RahulPatil. Can you answer for the question? [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54550576/how-to-update-system-time-and-time-zone-in-android)

Comment: @NewDeveloper, yes I will check your question  in 3hrs from now

Answer (score 1):

As an updated answer, this works with `Settings.Global`:

```
 @RequiresPermission("android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS")
    public void setSettingsAutomaticDateTimeIfNeeded() {
        String timeSettings = android.provider.Settings.Global.getString(
                this.getContentResolver(),
                android.provider.Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME);
        if (timeSettings.contentEquals("0")) {
            android.provider.Settings.Global.putString(
                    this.getContentResolver(),
                    android.provider.Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, "1");
        }
    }
```

Tested in October 2018.

Comment: Does it work without the need of the WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission?

Comment: @AntonioVlasic in my case on Android 6.0.1, it did in fact require the WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission (also required to be a system app, which is fine for us as it's our own custom rom, but may be an issue for others).