# How to update system time and time zone?

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to update the system time and time zone. This is system application. So I gave system application permissions. My code is

```
    try {

        AlarmManager alarmManager =
                (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(getSelectedDateFormat(mSelectedDateFormat)
                .parse(mEtDate.getText() +" "+ mEtTime.getText()));
        alarmManager.setTimeZone(mSpTimeZone.getSelectedItem().toString());
        alarmManager.setTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here when I update TimeZone and Time at a moment, Time is update wrongly. If I update time alone it update perfectly. Any idea what I am did wrong?

Comment: Have you added the following permission ?
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"/>

Comment: Yes. I added SET_TIME and SET_TIME_ZONE permissions..

Answer (score 0):

All system apps are not permitted to change the time zone.

In your application make file make sure that you have following tag

```
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
```

Only the system/priv-app are permitted to set the time zone.